# A portal containing multiple applications, with a single sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, portal, single-spa

I have been assigned the task of making a portal, that will "wrap" all of the web applications my firm uses. Right now, we are developing in Angular and React, when it comes to frontend, and .NET Core and Spring Boot, when it comes to backend.

We already have this kind of a portal, but it's old. It only support ASP.NET applications. But I would like to replicate the functionality. When a user tries to access it, a login form opens. After the user is done with the login form, he is redirected to the main page of the portal, which has a navbar, with other applications, which the user can or can not see based on his rights.

If anyone knows what is the best solution, or at least give me a direction in which I could continue my research, I would be very welcome. I'm sure this has already been done before, but I need some help.

I have tried using the Single SPA framework, but I'm not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: Hello.  Your question doesn't feel like a question.  Of the tags you added to your question (to attract experts on the matter), I'd say serve you no good because this is not a single sign-on problem.  I am here because I like single-spa, but you say you tried it but don't really say if you had a problem with your Proof of Concept, so what else can I add to the matter?  Maybe this broad question should be initially explored using AI to find what others have done.  Then decide what you want and move forward.

Comment: @JoséRamírez Hello, thank you for the answer. I get that my question doesn't feel like one, but that's because I'm not sure what to ask :)
I guess I'll go and talk to my friend ChatGPT.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic on stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic]). That being said, check Liferay. Despite being Java based, it allows Client extensions in any language or technology, and gives you full flexibility on the browser